# Excel - Cells Printing as ##### after Fit all Columns on One Page

Tags: excel, scaling

I had autosized all of the columns beforehand, but when I fit all columns on one page in the print screen some columns turn into #######. Is there a way to prevent this without manually going in and making those columns bigger? (The ####### does not show up on the actual excel sheet, the number that occupies the cell does)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're running into a tiny difference between the screen display and the printer's output. TBH, a different printer might even give correct output. A short VBA routine could cycle through the columns, first autofitting them then adding a small amount to the auto-fitted width. Since you seem to be using something like *1 page wide by xx tall* it shouldn't matter that much to the printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always the same column, I'd start by seeing if you can reduce the font size a little so that the width of the printed data isn't greater than the size of the column when the fit-to-one-page routine squeezes things together.

If you need an automated solution that will run whenever you get ready to fit-to-one-page and print, that's beyond my skills.  Maybe VBA code that adds the column widths, predicts the % they'll be reduced, and checks to see which columns need to have their font shrunk & by how much... not a small project, that.

But if you can live with a manual solution, I'd start by a small reduction in font size.  Or see if tweaking the margins helps -- tricks from college to get a "10 page paper"!

Comment: I think you're on to something. Let me try coding in a reduction of font size at the end of my code. If I do it then I will be autosizing the cells with the larger font and when i switch to the the smaller font the cell contents should show up every time. :)